# If $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space then is $A$ a closed subset of $K$?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Since $(X,d)$ is compact it is totally bounded so we will have a finite set $A_n$ such that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{x \in A_n} B_d\left(x,\frac{1}{n}\right)$ covers $(X,d)$. Now we take $A$ as the union of these$A_n$. Is $A$ closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about an interval $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric. You can choose each $A_n$ as a subset of the rational numbers, so $A$ also will be a subset of $\mathbb{Q}\cap [a,b]$.

The interior of $A$ is empty and the closure of $A$ is $[a,b]$. Hence $A$ is neither open or closed.

Comment: So $A$ t will not be compact right? As only closed subsets of compact metric space are compact

Comment: @smita In the cases where $A$ is not close, it will not be compact. To see this choose any point in $a \in X\setminus A$ (A not close means that such a point exists because closure of $A$ is $X$). By construction of $A$ there exist a sequence of elements of $A$ converging to $a$, and so any subsequence will also have $a$ as a limit. If $A$ was compact this will give you a contradiction because you just constructed a sequence with no converging subsequences whose limiit is in $A$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3989024/676808.

Comment: here's a link to the question as to why I am asking this one.I thought you can go through it.