# Prove that $(K,\delta)$ is a compact metric space.

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space. For $x ∈ X $ and $\epsilon > 0$, define

{$B_{\epsilon}(x) := {y ∈
X | d(x, y) < \epsilon}$}.

For $C ⊆ X$ and $\epsilon > 0$, define $B_{\epsilon}(C) := ∪_{x∈C}B_{\epsilon}(x)$.

Let K be the
set of non-empty compact subsets of X. For $C, C_0 ∈ K$, define $δ(C, C_0) = $inf{$\epsilon| C ⊆ B_{\epsilon}(C_0)$ and $C_0 ⊆ B_{\epsilon}(C)$}.

Assuming that it forms a metric space show that $(K, δ) $ is a compact metric space.

My attempt:

The metric space $(X,d)$ is compact so it is totally bounded.
Let $B=${$C_k$ } be a sequence of compact metric spaces in $K$. We need to show that the infinite set has a limit point.

$(X, d)$ is totally bounded so let $A_1$={$x_{1,1},x_{2, 1},....,x_{k_1,1}$} such that ${\cup {B_d(x_i,1) }} $ covers X for $i= (1,1),..,(k_1,1)$ and ${\cup {B_d(x_i,\frac{1}{2}) }} $ covers X for $i= (1,2),..,(k_2,2)$ ,so $A_2= x_{1,2},x_{2,2},...,x_{k_2,2}$

So we can generate a new sequence of compact metric space $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ as mentioned above.Now,let {$\cup {(A_i)}$}=$A$ .We take the closure $cl(A)$ which is the closed subset of $(X,d)$.Hence it is compact so it is in $(K,\delta)$.

> $(B_{\delta}(cl(A) \cap B)  /cl(A))\ne \phi$ for all $\epsilon>0$ is what we have to show to prove that $cl(A)$ is the limit point of the sequence {${C_k}$} to show that the sequence has bolzano weistrass property.

We pick an $\epsilon >0$ and proceed as ,

Now, $C_i \subset B_{\frac{1}{N_1}}(cl(A))$ where $\frac{1}{N_1} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $C_i \subset B_{\epsilon}(cl(A))$ where $C_i$ is any compact subset in the sequence {$C_k$} and $C_i$ can be chosen to be different from $cl(A)$.

Now, let $x \in Cl(A)$
then $x \in X$ and $x \in \cup B_d(x_i,\frac{1}{N_1})$ where $i=(1,N_1),(2,N_1),(3,N_1),...,(k_{N_1},N_1)$
then $d(x,x_i) < \frac{1}{N_1}$ and let $x_n \in C_i$ then $d(x_i,x_n) < \frac{1}{N_1}$ so $d(x,x_n) < \epsilon$ and the other case should also follow when $ x = x_i $ where $i=(1,N_1),(2,N_1),(3,N_1),...,(k_{N_1},N_1)$.
So $cl(A) \subset B_{\epsilon}(C_i)$.

Then $\delta(C_i,cl(A)) < \epsilon$ which allows me to conclude that $cl(A)$ is the limit point of the above mentioned seqeunce (as $\epsilon$ can be chosen arbitrarily).So by bolzano property I can claim the compactness.

Is my attempt ok? I have tried hard so that the notations are understandable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which is the question? (It is very hard to follow the own attempt. We have a lot of notations, and no leading idea for the many propositions. The $k_1$ comes from the heaven, and it has nothing to do with the given $C_1$ or whatever given data. To fix ideas, let $X$ be $[0,1]\subset\Bbb R$. Then i take $x_{1(k_1)},x_{2(k_2)}$ to be the points $1/3$, $2/3$. And the same values for all other. We have a lot of identical coverings of $X$. It is also hard to see that *"Let us give some $\epsilon>0$..."*  or so, and how to construct some $N(\epsilon)$ based on it. Please give a shape to the proof.)

Comment: I have tried to make it more comprehensible .I hope it is understandable now . I couldnt understand your last point .

Comment: I don't think $Cl(A')$ is a good candidate for the limit because it depends on all the set in the sequence, and a limit should not change if you change a finite number of terms of the sequence. My idea ( I am not sure if it works ) is to consider the sequence (of elements of X) $(x_{i,j})$ where $1\leq j\leq \infty$ and $1\leq i\leq k_j$. Then consider the set $C$ of limit points of all converging subsequences of $(x_{i,j})$. This is a nonempty subset of $X$ because $X$ is compact. I think it should not be very hard to prove that $C$ is a compact subset.

Comment: But I have assumed $cl(A')$ in such a way that it doesn't depend on the {${C_k}$}.I am taking the set $(C_n)'$ in such a way that elements cover $X$ with balls of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ and centres on the elements of $(C_n)'$.A union of such sets give me $A'$,then how would such a set depend on the sequence {$C_k$}?Is my notation confusing?

Comment: I have tried fixing my notation I hope it is better now

Comment: @smita Sorry, maybe I did not read well your definition of the sets $A_i$ ( I was thinking $A_i$ were the points of a subcover of $C_i$ not of $X$). But with your definition what is happening is that $cl(A)=X$.

Comment: Yes@Adrian I got it .I realize that I have successfully wasted two days on the problem without even hovering close to the solutions. When will I even get these types of problems right?I have done rudin chapter 2 yet I feel so stuck at the problems.

Comment: What is your intuition behind the hints that you gave.I am sorry if it sounds stupid but finding all the convergent subsequence will it not be an uncountable process?Can we do such things ?

Comment: @smita don't worry, fighting with the problems is usually the best way to learn, I will write a preliminary answer with my idea and I will complete it later

Comment: Yes @Adrian please drop a hint as an answer with your intuition. I will try to complete it. Thanks a lot for being so supportive and patience

Comment: @smita If this is an exercise of Rudin's book, maybe you get more lucky searching it by its number and the chapter of the book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will write here my idea in a more formal way, and see if it works. I will try to do as little change in your argument as possible.

**Idea:** Lets start with something easier. Prove that for any convergent sequence $\{ C_i\}_{i=0}^\infty$ the limit is in $K$. THat is, $K$ is closed.

First, we would like to know how the limit of a sequence of compact spaces would look like. We look at some special cases for intuition.

In the case that $C_{i+1}\subseteq C_i$ it makes sense that the limit is $\bigcap C_i$.

Next, we look at the interval [0,1] and the sequence $[0,\frac{1}{2}], [\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}], [\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}]... $ and so on. What is the limit here? it seems that it should be $\{1\}$ (can you prove it?) But no matter what it is, the points of the $C_i$ has to get "closer and closer" to the points of the limit set.

Take $A_i$ as a set of points (finite) such that $\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{k_i} B_d(x_{j,i},\frac{1}{i})$ covers $C_i$. With this sets, we can construct a sequence by first taking the elements of $A_1$ (ordered by the first index), then the elements of $A_2$ and so on. This is a sequence of elements of $X$, and as $X$ is a compact metric space, it will have (at least one) converging subsequences. So it makes sense to look at the set $C$ of the limit points of those subsequences.

Why this set is a good candidate for the limit? First if you look at the examples above, it coincides with the limit, or at least our idea of what the limit should be. Second, the set $C$ does not change if you change a finite set of the $C_i$'s, and most important (if  I am not wrong) it does not change if you choose any other set of points as your $A_i$'s (if the $C_i$'s are fixed).

Now, we have to prove that $C$ is compact. It is enough to prove that is closed. Try to show it, I will complete it later if you are not able to do it.

If all of this works. What we have left is to prove that $K$ is totally bounded. I don't see an easy proof of that right now but maybe you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is compact, so it is totally bounded; for each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $D_n$ be a finite $2^{-n}$-net in $X$, i.e., a finite subset of $X$ such that $X=\bigcup_{x\in D_n}B_d(x,2^{-n})$, and let $\mathscr{D}_n$ be the family of non-empty subsets of $D_n$.

Let $\epsilon>0$; there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $2^{-n}<\epsilon$. For $C\in K$ let

$$F=D_n\cap B_d(C,2^{-n})\in\mathscr{D}_n\,;$$

then $\delta(C,F)\le 2^{-n}<\epsilon$, so $\mathscr{D}_n$ is a finite $\epsilon$-net for $K$, and $K$ is totally bounded. To show that $K$ is compact, it only remains to show that $K$ is complete.

Let $\langle C_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a Cauchy sequence in $K$. Let

$$H=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\operatorname{cl}_X\left(\bigcup_{k\ge n}C_k\right)\in K\,,$$

and let $\epsilon>0$. If $\{n\in\Bbb N:C_n\nsubseteq B_d(H,\epsilon)\}$ is infinite, then $\bigcup_{k\ge n}C_k\nsubseteq B_d(H,\epsilon)$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so $\operatorname{cl}_X\left(\bigcup_{k\ge n}C_k\right)\setminus B_d(H,\epsilon)$ is a non-empty compact set for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and

$$H\setminus B_d(H,\epsilon)=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\left(\operatorname{cl}_X\left(\bigcup_{k\ge n}C_k\right)\setminus B_d(H,\epsilon)\right)\ne\varnothing\,,$$

which is absurd. Thus, for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $n_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $C_n\subseteq B_d(H,\epsilon)$ for all $n\ge n_\epsilon$.

Now suppose that $\{n\in\Bbb N:H\nsubseteq B_d(C_n,\epsilon)\}$ is infinite. There is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $\delta(C_k,C_\ell)<\frac{\epsilon}3$ whenever $k,\ell\ge m$. Fix $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\ge m$ and $H\nsubseteq B_d(C_n,\epsilon)$, and let $x\in H\setminus B_d(C_n,\epsilon)$. Let $k\ge n$. Then $\delta(C_k,C_n)<\frac{\epsilon}3$, so $C_k\subseteq B_d\left(C_n,\frac{\epsilon}3\right)$, and hence $B_d\left(C_k,\frac{\epsilon}3\right)\subseteq B_d\left(C_n,\frac{2\epsilon}3\right)$. But then

$$\begin{align*}
H&\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_X\left(\bigcup_{k\ge n}C_k\right)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_X\left(\bigcup_{k\ge n}B_d\left(C_k,\frac{\epsilon}3\right)\right)\\
&\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_X\left(B_d\left(C_n,\frac{2\epsilon}3\right)\right)\subseteq B_d(C_n,\epsilon)\\
&\subseteq H\setminus\{x\}\,,
\end{align*}$$

which is absurd.

Thus, there is an $m_\epsilon$ such that $H\subseteq B_d(C_n,\epsilon)$ for all $n\ge m_\epsilon$.

Putting the pieces together, we see that $\delta(H,C_k)\le\epsilon$ for all $k\ge\max\{n_\epsilon,m_\epsilon\}$ and hence that $\langle C_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $H$ in $\langle K,\delta\rangle$.